# Android Change language of speech to text to Japanese not working

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Hi I'm making a Japanese learning app for android. One of the features is to speak to the app in Japanese to check if you are saying words correctly. I got it working with `promptSpeechInput` but I did not like the `ui` getting in the way so I decided to go another rout and have my Fragment implement `RecognitionListener`. For some reason now Japanese is not working and it shows English words. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here is my code for my Speech Fragment

```
public class SpeechFragment extends Fragment implements RecognitionListener {

private TextView textViewInput;
private ToggleButton buttonSpeak;
private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
private Intent recognizerIntent;

public SpeechFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_speech, container, false);


    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.getContext());
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);

    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.JAPANESE);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);



    textViewInput = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewInput);
    buttonSpeak = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSpeak);
    buttonSpeak.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            } else {
                speech.stopListening();
            }
        }
    });

return view;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
    }

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    textViewInput.setText("Speak");
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
      }

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    buttonSpeak.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    textViewInput.setText(errorMessage);
    buttonSpeak.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";

    textViewInput.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
}

public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.JAPANESE);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
```

After that override the onActivityResult() method in your activity file(where you called the fragment)

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<String> words=data.getExtras().getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    //Here you can get the spoken words
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm using a Fragment and I have no OnActivityResult.

Also I found a error in my code above. I'm making a new intent intend of using recognizerIntent. Fixed that and still no luck.

I wen't to my settings and made Japanese my default Language and it worked but that's a dirty way of getting it to work.

Comment: If you are usiing the fragment then you have to define the onActvityResult() method in your activity file(place where you called fragment from activity).After that in fragment class you can call it by getActivity().startActivityForResult(....)

Comment: That again gave me a prompt which I did not want but thanks for the help.
You did however helped me with that intent and I got it working without the UI that pops up. Ill post the new intent code as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on the intent and got it working. I replaced Local.JAPANESE with ja_JP and it worked.

```
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ja_JP");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speak");
```